# Make footer stick to bottom without min-height:100%

Tags: html, css

Okay, so for the basic question *Make footer stick to bottom* there's the classic solution: wrap everything in a `div` with `position:relative` and `min-height:100%`. Like this tutorial [here](http://www.rafilabs.com/making-footers-stick-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-with-css/).

The problem arises here: inside the wrapper I have some `divs` for which I need the height in **percent**: `height:70%` for example. And to get this to work I need the `wrapper div` to have `height:100%`, NOT `min-height:100%`.

So how can I make the footer stick to bottom and still have inner `div`s with the `height` in percents?

Comment: have you considered what is going to happen to the content when the screen is too short?

Comment: you can use `position:fixed;bottom:0;` for your footer..

Comment: @Lal if I do that, for really long content the footer will overlap with the content

Comment: @zzzzBov yes, the inner div with height in percent has a min-height - in my case 400px, in case the screen is too small

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle and share the link with us..

Comment: @Lal I edited my question and included my site

Comment: In your page source, I can see that your `div` with id `footer` is inside the div `content_wrapper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I would change is remove the footer div from inside of the wrapper. Then I would also remove `height: 100%` for the wrapper. Setting height to 100% causes the height to be the length of the viewport height (height of your screen, not your webpage).

There is still some more issues, but those are two main ones i noticed from glancing at your web